# Use Certain Commandblock commands with @p or @a

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I originally wanted to attach the `/playsound random.orb`, when the scoreboard objective Bow got a value of 1 which was tracking `stat.useItem.minecraft.bow`, So when the player shot an arrow the sound would play, but if the player got too far away, the sound would not be heard.

I then tried to summon a Mine cart Command Block relative to the player using `@p` ,which would activate using an also spawned redstone block which would be removed instantly however the `/summon` and `/fill` commands don't support the `@p` or `@a`. Or any way to track player coordinates then use them to spawn blocks.

I couldn't think of another way to make the sound occur everywhere when a player/one player fires the bow.

Comment: Couldn't you summon the sound relative to the player?

Comment: I tried using /playsound random.orb @p But still if you move away from the command block itself the sound gets too quite to hear

Comment: That's interesting, I thought that the sound would play with the player.

Comment: It's what i thought would happen, Which is why I'm stuck wondering if there is some way to get the sound to remotely play at the selected player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you put in?
`/playsound <sound> <player> [x] [y] [z] [volume] [pitch] [minimumVolume]`

Also note that you can change the volume /\ and the minimum volume /. Using those to it should be heard by the player. Note also that you can do it to a persific player so if you want it to be heard by one player the have a low volume and target the player.

If that does not work, I have a other solution.

Sorce: [Minecraft Forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/recent-updates-and-snapshots/380602-the-new-command-in-1-6-1-playsound)

Comment: This has actually worked, Just set the volume to 10000000.0

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to always work at the position of the player, you could also do this:

```
execute as <player> at <player> run playsound <sound> <player> ~ ~ ~ [volume] [pitch] [minimumVolume]
```